# Django display search keyword and count in template

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

How to display the actual keyword and count in custom search form?

My Haystack custom search is working just fine but I'm having difficulties displaying the actual keyword and count.

When I was using the default Haystack urls the `{{ query }}` would display the actual keyword.

When using custom search form the `{{ query }}` and `{{ query.count }}` is empty.

**form.py**

```
class BusinessSearchForm(SearchForm):

def no_query_found(self):
    return self.searchqueryset.all()

def search(self):
    sqs = super(BusinessSearchForm, self).search()

    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    return sqs
```

**view.py**

```
def business_search(request):
form = BusinessSearchForm(request.GET)
businesslist = form.search()
paginator = Paginator(businesslist, 5) 
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    businesslist = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    businesslist = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    businesslist = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response('businesslist.html', {'businesslist': businesslist},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.html**

```
Your query {{ query }} has returned {{ query.count }} result{{ businesslist|pluralize }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass on `query` as context.

So something like this:

```
context = {
    'query': form.cleaned_data['q'],
    'businesslist': businesslist,
    'paginator': paginator,
}

return render_to_response('businesslist.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And you can use `paginator.count` to get number of results.

**template.html**

```
Your query {{ query }} has returned {{ paginator.count }} result{{ paginator.count|pluralize }}.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The `{{ query }}` keyword is now showing up however the `businesslist.count` is still blank. Any ideas? Do I have to add `.count()` somwhere in the `view.py`??

Comment: With out actually running the code myself. I'm not sure why its not working. I would suggest you have a look at this to give you better idea: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/views.py#L178

Comment: Got it all up and running! As per the `count`, these two are working: `{{ page.object_list|length }}` or `{{ page.paginator.count }}` Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

it is very easy as you can return context which is a dict and parse it at the frontend

in views.py file

```
    context = {
        'query': query,
        'result_list': Regs.objects.filter(pk__in=list_id),
    }

    return context
```

in template.html parse it as

```
    {{ object_list.result_list|length }} is the number of results for the query and  "{{ object_list.query }}" is the actual query entered by the user.
```